# What happened to mohn hamentaschen?

Tags: purim

I like mohn (poppy seed) hamantashen the best. I used to be able to obtain these pre-packaged in grocery stores and supermarkets until about 7-8 years ago, approx. Bakeries still make them, but they seem to be harder to find than they used to be.

Is it because of the younger generation that doesn't like this flavor that they have been making less of this? Why is it harder to find mohn hamentaschen?

If it makes a difference, I live in NY area. I can't say if this a localized phenomenon or not.

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Close, if not. It is related to Purim "simcha". No, it's not meant to be Purim Torah, either.

Comment: I don't find them hard to find

Comment: They are abundant in my neck of the woods. The NY area is quite large; are you sure it's not just your neighborhood bakery (or that they're not just sold out because they're so popular)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess a generation raised on candy prefers sweeter fillings that don't get stuck in your teeth. :D

Personally, I have no problems finding Mohn hamentaschen down here in Baltimore - they are just as common as any other flavor.

Though I guess that was the change - they used to be the MOST common flavor, until people realized that cherry/apricot/prune/chocolate/whatever was selling better, so they reduced production of the mohn and increased the others. It's not that they aren't making it per se, it's that they're making too little to satisfy market demand, apparently.

Comment: And that's market economics! It's nice when you have a tidy example of a theory that works in real life.